# Select list from list of IDs using persistent

Tags: haskell, haskell-persistent

In my application I need to be able to write a query that takes a list of IDs and returns a list of each of those records.

From what I can tell from the [yesod persistent page](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) I could do something like

```
selectList (UserId ==. 1 ||. UserId ==. 2 ||. UserId ==. 3) []
```

Which I believe would return a list containing user 1, 2 and 3 but I can't work out how I would write this query when I don't know the list or how long it will be at compile time.

How would I go about selecting a list of records using a list of IDs in Haskell persistent.

Comment: do you mean sthg like `selectList (UserId <-. [1..3]) []`?

Answer (score 3):

Persistent has several combinators for creating queries the one you are looking for is [`(<-.) :: PersistField typ => EntityField v typ -> [typ] -> Filter v`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.2/persistent-2.7.1/Database-Persist.html#v:-60--45-.).

Then your query can be simplified to

```
selectList [UserId <-. [1..3]] []
```

Comment: I got it working but I had to change it to `selectList [UserId <-. users] []` where users is of the type [UserId]. If you could edit the answer to that I will accept it.

Comment: @qwertie fixed it, sorry for the typo

Comment: It also can't be a list of ints, has to be a list of UserId or whatever type was created for the model ID.